# $|v|$ and $|x|$ factorizations (in Pumping lemma for context-free) have the same length?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

When i iterate $v$ and $x$ factorizations to see if a word is still in a language $L$, do i have to assume that $|v| = |x|$ always or could happen theirs lengths are different?.

I'm asking because i found a grammar for this language:
$L$ = { $a^nb^m,  |n-m|$ is even } , so it should be context-free.

But if i try to apply pumping-lemma using the word $a^nb^n$ , and i place $v$ in the first half and $x$ in the second half, and i assume that $|v|$ and |x| lengths could be different, it could happen the number of $a$ could be odd and the number of $b$ could be even, so an odd number minus an even number is an odd number, so the word is not in the language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Note: the language is even regular.

The pumping says that **THERE EXISTS** a decomposition $s = uvwxy$ verifying the three conditions. It does not mean that such a decomposition is unique, nor that any decomposition works.

In your example, a decomposition $v = a$ and $x = b$ works, but so does $v = \varepsilon$ and $x = bb$, or $v = a$ and $x = aaaaa$, and so on…

Comment: So if i find a decomposition where for every n it doesn't violate any of three conditions, i can try to find a grammar and eventually say the language is context-free, right?

Comment: No because the pumping lemma is not an equivalence, therefore it cannot be used to prove that a language is context-free (meaning there are some mean languages that are not context-free but still verify the conclusions of the lemma).